# Getting Last Updated record filed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want last updated row for this record 24763

```
nc_comment_id   nc_id   nc_user_id  nc_comment_added_by nc_comment  nc_comment_added_on
1               24763   2051        Amit sharma         nc created  2013-09-23 17:45:00.000
2               24763   2051        Amit Sharma         nc updated      2013-09-23 17:45:00.000
44              24763   2051        Pravin              NULL        2013-10-22 12:13:48.000

45              24789   2050        Arun                    nc_created      2013-10-22 12:13:48.000
```

I want this record with sql query

```
44              24763   2051        Pravin              NULL        2013-10-22 12:13:48.000
```

Answer (score 2):

For MSSQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tablename
WHERE nc_id = 24763
ORDER BY nc_comment_added_on desc
```

for MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE nc_id = 24763
ORDER BY nc_comment_added_on desc
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try below query

```
select top 1 * from tbla where nc_id=24763 order by nc_comment_id desc
```